# Report the min value from a columns as a reference to another value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to report the minimum value on one cell, so that min value should be from one column and looking from another column.

I did that with the average value but I am not able to do it with the min. 
The example on the average value is:

```
=IF(ISERR(AVERAGEIF($A$3:$A$987,T4,F$3:F$987)),"",AVERAGEIF($A$3:$A$987,T4,F$3:F$987)).
```

Basically I would like to do the same but with the minimum value.

Comment: Like `=MIN(A:A)`? Or even `=SMALL(A:A,1)`

Comment: Yes, but the cell that I would like the min number is should be find me the min number from that column when this other column is equal to x...

Comment: So only if the minimum in a column is n, then find minimum in the other column? Or find the minimum in a column and then tell you what is in the same row but in a different column? Which columns? What if there is more than one instance of the minimum?

Comment: I would like to send you a screenshot if possible so I can explain myself better

Comment: Gary's Student's answer finds the col B value associated with the min value in col A.  Are you saying col B can have multiples of the same values and you want to find the min col A value for a specific col B value?  For example, if Darth Vader appeared 3 times in col B, you want to find the min col A value associated with Darth Vader?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data to help explain the question. See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Say we want to find the minimum value in column **A** and return the associated name from column **B**.  Try:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(MIN(A:A),A:A,0))
```

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=MIN(IF($A$3:$A$987=T4,F$3:F$987,""))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter.

Comment: That works but it is giving me the value 0 when there is no value on the column where we look up

Comment: That is fine but I would like to add another part as it is giving me a 0 min value when there is nothing on the cel.